# iOS: Best way to implement settings with multiple sections

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitableview

I'm implementing a settings screen in my app that has several sections.

Section-wise:

1. May be something like general app settings like:

   - only download over WiFi
   - disable auto dimming
2. May be something for a different category of settings lik:

   - default text size
   - etc.

So... In total I'll have 4 or 5 of these sections and each will contain 2 - 5 options.
Some of the sections will have headers and others may not.

I've attached a screenshot of the Vesper app to show the idea I'm talking about.

**My question is this:**
Is it best to use a `UITableView` with Sections (grouped) to accomplish this, or just separate `UIViews` manually placed at the positions I want them?
(*For what it's worth, I'm not using Interface Builder*)

[image: Vesper Settings]

Comment: Are you wanting these to be in the actual settings application or your application in a settings screen?

Comment: It's very common to use a group-style table view for such a screen.

Comment: I personally find very useful using a group-style table view: it allows you to easily make an "iOS like" setting page and particularly it provides automatic scrolling in case you will need to add more settings later on that don't fit in a single screen.

Comment: you might get better response if you migrated the question to http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i'd suggest `UITableView` as well (_and maybe make it collapsable_). It's quicker to construct than using `UIView` objects.

Comment: @Tony: in the application in an settings screen.

Thanks, everyone. I think I was initially second guessing whether or not to do a `UITableIVew` because I'll have to have custom views inside each `UITableView` row. But it makes sense to use the grouped `UITableView`.

Comment: This question belongs on ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, `UITableView`s only take care of presenting and reusing `UITableViewCell`s, which inherit from `UIView`, so your question is basically "should I reinvent the functionality the table view already provides?"

And the answer is no, you shouldn't.

Even though you won't be getting much out of the "reuse" mechanic of table views, you will still be able to use everything else, the ability to hide/show rows animatedly, maybe some of the cells are identical (like text weight cells) and can be reused from the same identified queue, etc.

And if you want to implement a settings outside the app, then take a look at the [settings bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html), you don't even need to code, you just link a few plists together and get an interface done for you.